# How to import and export data from csv file to HTML?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I want To export data from HTML to CSV file and display that data to user as well using python just like Sign up page i want to save that data in csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking about converting a .csv to HTML table or the other way around but for either case:

**Converting from HTML table to .csv**

You can use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the table.

**Converting from .csv to HTML table**

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) will do this for you:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("foo.csv")
data.to_html("bar.html")
```

Comment: I want to create a csv file for student and the i want to add student data to csv file from html form